# Apply style to only some list items in Ui Fabric Nav component

Tags: css, reactjs, office-ui-fabric

[image]

Please look at the attached screenshot. There is a list there, where some items have an eye. The eye indicates that they are hidden (and not important for the user). The icon however, has the opposite effect - it draws attention instead of saying "don't worry about this".

My thought of solution is to apply an opacity style to only the rows with the eye icon, but i'm having a hard time proceeding with this.  I cannot, however, simply disable the rows (although that color would be perfect) - the user must be able to click it. I cannot simply grab whatever has an icon and apply a style either, as that would mess up the chevron rows.

So is there any clever trick to this problem? Does anyone know how this can be solved?

(Ui fabric documentation about the nav component is [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/#/controls/web/nav).)

Comment: The same way you're adding an icon to specific rows you can add a class style to them.

Comment: I can? All row stuff i'm doing is through the INavLink interface. There is no "class" property there besides the ones related to the icon?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I forced the "eye-icon" rows to be rendered as anchors, and then applied a custom style to them using a selector from the compositeLink style property